# Azure FuncApp zip deploy fails with ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool Max retries exceeded

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I am trying to deploy the FunctionApp via AzureCLI@1 task in DevOps pipeline, and it fails for the deployment part. Up until that step, it can create resources (Function, Storage), but fails for deployment. The function is in ASE, and the agent is a hosted Ubuntu agent, which should have inbound access to ASE.

```
task: AzureCLI@1
  inputs: 
    AzureConnectionType: AzureResourceManager
    connectedServiceNameARM: Connection
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: az functionapp deployment source config-zip --name $(function_name)  --resource-group $(resource_group) --src $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
  displayName: Deploy Function
```

---

```
2018-12-04T15:23:03.4429931Z ##[debug]exec tool: /bin/bash
2018-12-04T15:23:03.4430783Z ##[debug]arguments:
2018-12-04T15:23:03.4431067Z ##[debug]   /tmp/azureclitaskscript1543936981172.sh
2018-12-04T15:23:03.4431706Z [command]/bin/bash /tmp/azureclitaskscript1543936981172.sh
2018-12-04T15:25:17.7088017Z ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='funcapp.scm.ase.p.azurewebsites.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5dea8abc88>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',))
2018-12-04T15:25:17.7088860Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-12-04T15:25:17.7089548Z   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
2018-12-04T15:25:17.7089903Z     (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
2018-12-04T15:25:17.7090516Z   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
2018-12-04T15:25:17.7091216Z     raise err
2018-12-04T15:25:17.7091797Z   File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
2018-12-04T15:25:17.7092230Z     sock.connect(sa)
2018-12-04T15:25:17.7092778Z TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Comment: I am facing the same error, did you find any workaround?